# How can I enable parallelism via pytest -nauto if pytest-xdist is installed?

Tags: python, pytest, xdist

To enable parallel tests, one has to install `pytest-xdist` and use pass the `-nauto` option to `pytest` to use all available CPUs. I would like to enable `-nauto` by default, but still make `pytest-xdist` optional. So this would not work:

```
[pytest]
addopts = -nauto
```

Is there a way to enable pytest parallelism by default if `pytest-xdist` is installed? (It should also be possible to disable it again with `pytest -n0` if desired.)

I guess that some kind of `conftest.py` hook has to be written? It is [possible](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#optionally-using-hooks-from-3rd-party-plugins) to detect installed plugins, but [pytest_configure](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_configure) is ran after loading plugins which might be too late. Besides, I am not sure how options can be added at that point (or how to configure directly manipulate xdist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether the `xdist` options group has `numprocesses` arg defined. This indicates that `pytest-xdist` is installed and the option will be handled. If this is not the case, your own dummy arg will ensure the option is known to `pytest` (and safely ignored):

```python
# conftest.py

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    argdests = {arg.dest for arg in parser.getgroup('xdist').options}
    if 'numprocesses' not in argdests:
        parser.getgroup('xdist').addoption(
            '--numprocesses', dest='numprocesses', metavar='numprocesses', action='store',
            help="placeholder for xdist's numprocesses arg; passed value is ignored if xdist is not installed"
    )
```

Now you can leave the option in the `pytest.ini` even if `pytest-xdist` is not installed; however, you will need to use the long option:

```
[pytest]
addopts=--numprocesses=auto
```

The reason for that is that short options are reserved for `pytest` itself, so the code above doesn't define or use it. Should you really need the short option, you have to resort to the private method:

```python
parser.getgroup('xdist')._addoption('-n', '--numprocesses', dest='numprocesses', ...)
```

Now you can use the short option in the config:

```
[pytest]
addopts=-nauto
```

Comment: The `options` property is not publically documented, is it okay to rely on it?

Comment: Unfortunately, neither `OptionGroup` nor `Argument` objects are documented in the [API reference](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#objects), so no guarantees here. In general, I don't like this solution because adding useless arguments feels like a hack. I will think of a better solution, but right now, reconfiguring `xdist` looks even worse than hacking around the cli parser.

Comment: It's indeed a bit hacky and does not allow one to differentiate between `pytest -nauto` (as given by the user) and one implied by the default configuration (in the former case one might want to error out directly). For now I have decided to require xdist to be installed when pytest is in use, that's simpler.